# (Android) Create RecyclerView with strings from list

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview

I have a `List<String> listOfNames` that contains names. How to print them all using RecyclerView?

Comment: please add more details what you tried ?

Comment: I have found many different tutorials but each one was too much complicated for me, e.g. click button to show text from TextView in RecyclerView. I just want very simple answer: I have to use RecyclerView, don't know it yet at all, I need to print all elements from a list and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a simple way of doing this and after some time of fiddling around, I think I have found a way.

Here I use an ArrayList of Strings.

**Adapter Class**

```
public class TagsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TagsAdapter.TagsViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    public TagsAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TagsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_tags_chips, parent, false);

        return new TagsAdapter.TagsViewHolder(layoutView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TagsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tagText.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class TagsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tagText;

        public TagsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tagText = view.findViewById(R.id.chipTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the Activity or fragment you want to show the recycler view, initialize your recycler view to the view in the xml

**Tags.Java**

```
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
```

In the same place add this method. I am assuming that the array list already has strings in it

```
private void getTags() {
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.view);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        //I have made my recycler view horizontal, if you want it vertical, just change the horizontal above to vertical.
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new TagsAdapter(tagsArray);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I know this is an old question but might help someone who wants a simple and straightforward way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Simple example for recycler view.

Follow below steps:

1. Declare in global this variable

   ```
   private RecyclerView recyclerview;
   ```
2. Use this where you get response from server and make one model class using GSON plugin just copy and paste your response.After use that.

   ```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   CreateYourModel createYourModel = gson.fromJson(response_data, YourActivity.class);

   RecyclerAdapter  mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(createYourModel);

   RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
   recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
   recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
   recyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
   ```
3. This is your Recycler adapter just use same.

   ```
   public class RecyclerAdapter extends         RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

   private CreateYourModel mList;

   public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   public TextView tvdate;

   public MyViewHolder(View view) {
       super(view);
       tvdate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdate);

   }
   }


   public RecyclerAdapterCreateYourModel mList) {
   this.mList = mList;
   }

   @Override
   public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
           .inflate(R.layout.youritemview, parent, false);

   return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

   holder.tvsummuryloan_repayment_date.setText(setyourdatafromlist);

   }

    @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
   return mList.size();
   }
   }
   ```

You can follow any tutorial on google.

Thanks